# Actionscript trouble connection

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm took it upon me to help a friend on an adobe flash problem thinking that it would be a logical problem but i realized that i got way ahead of myself once i saw the actionscript code, well kinda... looks a lot like java to me but then again, not my area of expertise.

Problem seems to lie in the script area, being that, a button being clicked on is not checking login & password fields so it could log the user in.

So I know it's kind of a long shot coming here copying code lines & to ask for something really abstract, but hey what if someone surfing has the needed insight to at least point me in the right direction ?

So here's the picture :

[swf view from adobe flash cs6 trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr4r6.jpg)

The script at frame 35 :

```
boite.login_lbl.text = ((_root.login_lbl != undefined && _root.login_lbl != "") ? _root.login_lbl : "Votre login");
boite.pass_lbl.text = ((_root.pass_lbl != undefined && _root.pass_lbl != "") ? _root.pass_lbl : "Votre mot de passe");
```

The script at frame 49 :

```
_root.bIsEDOCEmbed = (_root.pEDOCAPI != undefined);

_root.focustxt = '';

logintext.onSetFocus = function() { _root.focustxt = 'login'; }
passtext.onSetFocus = function() { _root.focustxt = 'pass'; }

logintext.onKillFocus = function() { _root.focustxt = ''; }
passtext.onKillFocus = function() { _root.focustxt = ''; }

function myOnKeyDown() {
  if (Key.isDown(Key.ENTER)) {
    if (_root.focustxt == 'login') {
        Selection.setFocus(passtext);
    } else {
        Selection.setFocus(entrer);
        entrer.onRelease();
    }
  }
}

var monEcouteur = new Object();
monEcouteur.onKeyDown = myOnKeyDown;
Key.addListener(monEcouteur);

var action = 'auth';
var intro = '1';

if (_root.bIsEDOCEmbed) {
    var edoc_trytologin = '1';
    var internet_is_alive = _root.pEDOCAPI.isInternetAlive();
}

if ((_root.message_txt == '') || (_root.message_txt == undefined)) message_clip._visible = false;

entrer.onRelease = function() {
    if ((logintext.text != "") && (passtext.text != "")) {
        getURL(_root.basedir + "index.php" ,"_self","POST");
    }
}

if (_root.logo_file != undefined && _root.logo_file != "") {

    var img1:mcio.TImage = mcio.TImage(this.attachMovie(mcio.TImage.id, "img1", this.getNextHighestDepth()));
    img1._x = 176;
    img1._y = 104;
    img1.setSize(160, 85);

    img1.load(_root.logo_file);
}
```

And the script at frame 76 :

```
stop();
```

So i figured that actionscript coding is depending on a timeline (that took me a little while) & that frame 35 sets label in front of each field login & password telling the user what to type inside them;

Frame 49 first sets a global variable _root.bIsEDOCEmbed to _root.pEDOCAPI as long as it is different from undefined (i guess a php null value) but not knowing where it was defined first (_root.pEDOCAPI);

Then lines 5 to 9 act like a html input placeholder attribute;

Function line 10 checks on enter keyboard key that if it is hit from the login field, it jumps to the password one otherwise goes to the onRelease attribute of the 'entrer' object;

Lines 22 to 24 declare a 'monEcouteur' object calling the function from line 10 once a key is pressed;

Lines 26 & 27 are two variables being declared than defined;

If at line 29 defines a variable & check if there's a internet connection from the looks of it;

If at line 34 set a variable to false if another one is undefined & a character empty string;

Line 36 defines the entrer object 's attribute (that i'd call an anonymous function) and it checks that whether login & password fields are filled so it could send the data to the index.php file via post method;

Finally last lines are decorative & no real logic is involved here.

So my questions are : 
Am I wrong somewhere along my guesses 'cause that's all they are.
And if not, what did I miss so that when the button is being clicked on, it does not send data to the index.php (var_dump($_POST); at the start of the index.php shows nothing) ?

Many thanks if you kept on reading till here, first post here.

Comment: i can't see the part where this code sends any kind of data to the index.php...this looks like a very old code

Comment: it is indeed, I thought the part sending code to the index.php was once the entrer's onRelease' attribute was set but I could have been wrong all along.